# why is rabbitmq management plugin reports discrepancy in statistics?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, rabbitmq-management

I am using rabbitmq server along with celery. I have a queue, to which tasks are published by producers. Tasks are auto-acknowledged. But I am seeing discrepancy in what rabbitmq is reporting. In the Message rates, it's showing that there's no message being acknowledged/published/delivered, since last one minute, but queued messages are dropping continuously.

[image: RabbitMQ Queue]

Is this expected behavior ? OR there's something taking place under the hood.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

"Queued messages" is a sliding window of the message count in the queue. Notice that the far right of the graph matches the current unacknowledged message count in the queue, about 12K.

The other graph, "Message rates", is the rate of messages per second within a sampling interval.

In short, the two graphs are measuring two very different things - a count, and a rate.

You can read more about RabbitMQ's stats here: [link](https://cdn.rawgit.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.7.7/priv/www/doc/stats.html).